# Vue.set() alternative for change the entire object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity

As in the title, I want to know if there is alternative method for `Vue.set()` for changing the entire object instead of one property.

Vue.set():

```js
this.$set(this.object, 'price', 420);
```

What I'm looking for:

```js
this.$something(this.object, { 'price': 420 })
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with `this.object = { 'price': 420 }` ?

Comment: It's not reactive in Vue.js
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/so-what-actually-is-vue-set

Answer (score 0):

Try with spread syntax

```js
this.object = {
  ...this.object,
  price: 420,
}
```

Comment: That would work in raw JavaScript, but this statement wouldn't be reactive in Vue. See this: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/so-what-actually-is-vue-set